# Can an entity be created in the persistent storage like DB for GET REST Api call?

Tags: rest, http, get

I have an REST API exposed as a service which is supposed to return the list of entities for a domain type in my application. The Http method used is GET.

My question is can this API create another entity belonging to some other type during its execution?

Answer (score 0):

During a `GET` no other entity can be created. The reason for this is that `GET` is [safe and idempotent](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/). You must be able to execute it again and again without changing server state.